# ML.NET Column attribute does not contain 'ordinal'

Tags: c#, .net-core, ml.net

Trying to allocate values to my TrainingModel in ML.net but when i try to use the column attribute, it wont accept 'ordinal' as a parameter.

```
   [Column(ordinal: "0", name: "label")]
    public string FeedBackText { get; set; }

    [Column(ordinal: "1")]
    public bool IsGood { get; set; }
```

The error message that my intelissense throws is:

`The best overload for 'columnAttribute does not have a parameter named 'orginal'`

`cannot resolve symbol 'ordinal'`

Comment: Can you share a link to the documentation for `Column`? I see a `ColumnName` attribute, but not a `Column` one.

Comment: Quick google turned up this https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/3137. Seems `ColumnAttribute` is `ColumnNameAttribute` in version 0.11.

Comment: What version of ML.NET are you using?

Comment: neither contain a definition for 'oridnal'

Comment: @Jon i am using 1.4.0

Comment: Try using the `LoadColumn(0)` attribute instead. The parameter tells what ordinal it is. For the label, you can add the `ColumnName("Label")` attribute to it.

Comment: @Jon like so?        [LoadColumn(0)]
       ColumnNameAttribute("label")
        public string FeedBackText { get; set; }

Comment: this doesnt work eithjer:/

Comment: Try this - `[LoadColumn(0), ColumnName("Label")]`. Both should point to the Microsoft.ML.Data namespace.

Comment: @ jon thank you! it works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

column is deprecated, the update version is:

[LoadColumn(0), ColumnName("label")]

Comment: "label" *may* need to be capitalized for when you train the model. I think it expects "Label" unless you specify the label column name to be "label".